Reading Recommendations for Various (Protestant) Denominations
I'm looking for reputable books for a thorough summation (and/or defense) of beliefs for the Methodist, Pentecostal, Baptist, and Presbyterian (or, more broadly, reformed) denominations. Any suggestions?

Sorry, but book recommendations generally aren't allowed here. There are just too many books about each denomination!

Dang, okay. I wasn't aware of that. Perhaps I should've looked over the guidelines before asking.

Any good and recent Protestant systematic theology book should do this comparative theologies in the standard division of topics (such as the doctrine of scripture, theology proper (about the Godhead), Christology, pneumatology, soteriology, ecclesiology, eschatology, sin, providence, sacraments, etc.).  Of course if you pick up a Reformed systematic theology book, they would champion the Reformed doctrines and may mispresent the others.  So look for a more scholarly systematic theology books.  I heard evangelical Donald G. Bloesch's 7-volume Christian Foundations (1992-2006) is a good one, and used by a respectable seminary attended by a friend of mine.
For a summation and defense of beliefs of various factions within Protestantism (and sometimes also Catholic and Eastern Orthodox) on a particular doctrine, I cannot recommend the IVP Spectrum Multiview book series and the Zondervan Academic Counterpoints book series highly enough.  For each view, the authors of other views in the book will respond (in a chapter), and I think in one series the author of that view can provide a response to the response.

Thanks for the recommendations!

Welcome to C.SE.  Please do the tour.  If you find the answer helpful you can vote up.  If there is another area that you need more answering, please refine your question to be more specific, or provide a comment for the answer author.  Once you're happy, you can "accept" the answer by clicking the checkmark.  Otherwise, wait until others submit their answers.  They may also provide comments for improving your question so it can be a valuable part of C.SE library of Q&A, as this site is not a forum or a helpdesk.
